# How to do use While loop with many conditions to meet?#

Tags: python, list, if-statement, while-loop

I managed to make 2 players take turn playing but it stops after the 2nd player entered her answer. I want to do the While loop however I seriously ran out of idea how to. I get it in my mind like I want the two players to keep playing until 3 position of 0s or Xs are filled but putting it in code I really need help.

Below is my condition but I want it to continue asking the player until these condition are met

```
if list1[0,1,2] == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [0] , list3[0]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [1], list3[2]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list2 [0] , list2 [1], list2[2])== 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list3 [0] , list3 [0], list3[0]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [1] , list2 [1], list3[1]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [2] , list2 [2], list3[2]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [1], list3[0]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [1] , list2 [1], list3[1]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [2] , list2 [2], list3[2]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [0], list3[0]) == 'x':
print ('Congrats! x won!')
elif (list1[0,1,2] == 'o':)
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [0] ,list3[0]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [1], list3[2]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list2 [0] , list2 [1], list2[2]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list3 [0] , list3 [0], list3[0]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [1] , list2 [1], list3[1]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [2] , list2 [2], list3[2]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [1], list3[0]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [1] , list2 [1], list3[1]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [2] , list2 [2], list3[2]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!')
elif (list1 [0] , list2 [0], list3[0]) == 'o':
print ('Congrats! o won!') 
else
```

Comment: Wait, is that a tic-tac-toe with 3 columns, and you're checking if someone won?

Comment: None of your conditions will ever be True, because you are comparing different objects. I suggest you to have a look at [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: Yes , I used 3 lists. list1 , list2 and list3

Comment: This code gets you a warning from the Department of Redundancy Department!

Comment: Next time, please remember to give a brief overview of the problem. People shouldn't have to guess you are trying to implement a tic-tac-toe game.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to have your board as a list of 3 lists (with 3 elements each).

With [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), you can avoid many unnecessary repetitions :

```
board = [['x', None, 'o'],
         ['o', 'x', None],
         ['o', None, 'x']
         ]


def three_in_row(board, player):
    return any(all(board[j][i] == player for i in range(3)) for j in range(3))


def three_in_column(board, player):
    return any(all(board[i][j] == player for i in range(3)) for j in range(3))


def three_in_diagonal(board, player):
    return all(board[i][i] == player for i in range(3)) or\
        all(board[i][2 - i] == player for i in range(3))


print three_in_row(board, 'x')
# False
print three_in_column(board, 'x')
# False
print three_in_diagonal(board, 'x')
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def check_line(line):
    if line[0]==line[1] and line[1]==line[2]:
        return line[0]
    return ' '

def check_win(board):
    #check horizontals
    for row in board:
        res=check_line(row)
        if res != ' ':
            return res

    #check verticals
    x=0
    for col in board[0]:
        res=check_line([board[y][x] for y in range(0, 3)])
        x+=1
        if res != ' ':
            return res

    #check diagonals
    for diagonal in ( [board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]], [board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]]):
        res = check_line(diagonal)
        if res != ' ':
            return res

    return ' '

def show_winner(list1, list2, list3):
    winner=check_win([list1, list2, list3])
    if winner!=" ":
        print("Congrats! {0} won!".format(winner))

list1=['o', 'x', 'x']
list2=['o', 'x', ' ']
list3=['x', 'o', ' ']
show_winner(list1, list2, list3)
```